# Is it required device Id and Registration Id for C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am having some problems in doing C2DM, I research a lot, but i did not get the proper way to do it. So i am asking a question.
My Questions are:

1). What is the difference between Registration Id and Device Id?

2). Is it Required both the id's for push Notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Registration ID**

> An ID issued by the C2DM servers to the Android application that
>   allows it to receive messages. Once the application has the
>   registration ID, it sends it to the third-party application server,
>   which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive
>   messages for a given application. In other words, a registration ID is
>   tied to a particular application running on a particular device.

You can find the source of Registration ID [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#arch).

**Device ID** might be the unique identification ID of a particular device, as in IMEI/IMSI number or something of the sort.

AFAIK, both are needed to get C2DM working.